# Why Safari shows "No Inspectable Applications" during remote debugging with iOS 6 device?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, safari, web-inspector

When I connect my iOS 6 device for remote debugging for testing my mobile web application, The safari develop menu with my device name shows "No Inspectable Applications".

I have enabled web inspector ON in my device safari device settings.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have private browsing enabled in `Settings > Safari`, you will not be able to use remote debugging. If you turned off private browsing, it will work like a charm.

Comment: Any other reasons why it might not work? I'm convinced that this feature became slightly broken in a recent Safari (desktop) update. I can see Safari views, but not UIWebViews within another application

Comment: @derrylwc Do you mean that you could not able to debug the UIWebViews in the application using Safari developer options in Mac because of recent update?...

Comment: I found that in Safari Settings on the iPhone I also needed to Clear History, and Clear Cookies and Data.

Comment: For me, I had to update to the latest version of Safari (7.1) in order to debug Safari on my iPad running iOS 8.

Comment: Thanks @Liam, I had to update to Safari 7.1 on my Mac as well. However I first needed to enable the "Debug" menu in the App Store, because Safari 7.1 is pre-release. I found this setting: `defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true` from [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/26624393#26628360).

Comment: I couldn't find the setting mentioned in this post (iOS 9), but disabling "Do not track" seemed to fix things

Comment: In my case I killed safari on my Mac and restarted again that did the trick.

Answer (score 55):

An update for iOS 9 (using OSX El Capitan):

> On your mobile device under Settings -> Safari -> Fraudulent Website
>   Warning = OFF [default = ON]
>
> I also needed to re-connect the iPhone after changing this setting

This solved it for me.

Comment: I also needed to re-connect the iPhone after changing this setting.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 53):

Starting from iOS 16.4 one has to manually mark the WKWebView as inspectable to allow Safari debugging:

```
#if DEBUG
       if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
          webView.isInspectable = true
       }
#endif
```

Comment: thank you! took me ages to figure this out

Comment: In which file and where i have to add this ?

Comment: @AbhaySingh right after creating a webview instance. For example, 
`let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
webView.isInspectable = true
`

Comment: It's showing app name but below about:blank which is not inspectable

Comment: Great help! Thanks.

Comment: Hi @IvanNikitin Can you please guide in which file in need to create this webview instance ?

Comment: @HardikThakkar you don't need to create a new webview instance. You should set the isInspectable property for the instance you already have.

Answer (score 30):

I recently had problems debugging a UIWebView in desktop Safari – and it turns out the problem was with my Xcode configuration for the app. The most recent build had been provisioned for production, rather than for Testing. After re-building the app for Testing, it showed up once more in the Safari Debug menu :-)

Comment: this was my problem, I was trying to debug a production app made with ionic2. What I did was: `1.ionic build ios`, 2. connect de ipad to pc then in Xcode I've selected the device; 3. Develop>Run

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue eventually I understand that the problem is with the Xcode settings.

To solve this issue:

#### Enable Safari Debug

First of all verify that on the device you have enabled the Safari debugger (on the device go to: `Settings >> Safari >> Advanced >> Enable Debug`; or iOS 9+ turn on: `Settings >> Safari >> Advanced >> Web Inspector`). If you've done this you will see your device in Safari >> Develop. if you see your device but you don't see your application under it, instead "`no inspectable application`", check your Xcode settings.

#### Xcode

**1. Change Build Configuration:**

Right click on the project name (under the play/run button) and select 'Edit Schema...', in the 'Edit Schema' window under 'Run' tab change the 'Build Configuration' to 'Debug' (instead of 'Release')

**2. Change the Code Signing:**

Click on the project name in the files tree, to display the project settings.
Select the 'Build Settings' tab. Change the 'Provision Profile' to 'Automatic'. Change the 'Code Sign Identity' to 'iOS Developer'.

Note that changing the code signing will prevent you from release versions for production, however you will be able to debug your application.

Comment: This answer helped me realize my problem was that I was trying to debug a TestFlight build -which won't work. It needs to be a Debug build -which for me was by connecting my device and pressing the Play button for it in Xcode

Answer (score 21):

A few things to try:

1. On your iPhone/iPad, double-tap the Home button to bring up the list of running apps, close Safari (or appropriate Web App), then reopen
2. Quit/reopen Safari on the Mac
3. Unplug/plug back in iOS device

As a side note, I *can* attach to Safari with private browsing enabled on the iOS device.

Comment: I can second these observations. Sometimes the USB cable and port are also factors. Sometimes it started working after just waiting a while. Weird.

Comment: can we do remote debugging on apps that are released via OTA(release not debug) ?

Comment: @Dunc - Just now I read somewhere that apps that has provisioning profile other than developer such as adhoc and distribution can not remote debugging using safari....

Comment: @Durai I can debug a live app downloaded from the app store (so distribution profile).  It's one of our own apps, so maybe something to do with my particular Mac/iPhone certificates.  I suggest you try yourself.

Comment: @Dunc - Thanks for updating me this info.

Comment: This worked perfectly for website testing contexts (iOS Safari + MacOS Safari). Just quit the iOS Safari on the Simulator, and restart it. Then it shows up on the MacOS Safari's Developer menu. Thx!

Answer (score 7):

I went to `Settings > Safari > Advanced` and toggled the `Web Inspector` switch from `on` to `off` to `on` again. That did it for me!

Comment: Had to do it twice, but this finally seems to have put the problem to sleep for the moment. I also turned on the `allow automation` setting, don't know if that helped or not.

Answer (score 3):

If you just installed XCode 9, do not forget to install Safari 11, or you will see "no inspecable applications"

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Safari 11.0.3 on High Sierra. The only thing that worked for me is installing **Safari Technology Preview** from [here](https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you aren't connected to a VPN.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had Safari 10.0.2, running on El Capitan and when trying to run apps on the Simulator (iphone 7), I did not even have the Simulator option in the Safari's Develop menu. Updating to Sierra, solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue with rebuilding the app with new key - certificate (p12) and provisioning profile. My developer account and certificates expired, so it just stopped recognizing my PhoneGap app in Developer menu.

Answer (score 1):

After all the answers here failed to resolve the issue for me, I figured out that installing the [Safari Technology Preview version](https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/) worked well.

Install this beta of Safari, launch it, enable developer tools in advanced preferences, and your phone will appear in the develop bar (provided a page in mobile Safari is open).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is coming here like me...
iOS 16.4 had changes the block this.

cordova-ios put in a fix in 6.3.0 (so upgrading might help some of you - https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/1300)

However, Ionic cordova apps can use the Ionic Webview, which was my issue.  I finally found this...

[Ionic app - Cordova - Safari Debug not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76434408/ionic-app-cordova-safari-debug-not-working)

...which linked to this...

https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/pull/677

After I manually made the change in the xCode project (CDBWKWebViewEngine.m file) I was FINALLY able to debug.

I still had settings on the device for debugging, the xCode schema set to debug, etc, but this was the missing link.

Answer (score -2):

I was trying to get this working via the iOS simulator and none of the previously stated answers worked, even though I tried them all.
Instead, running the following worked:

```
npm install -g ios-sim
```

After that, once I started the application, the simulator appeared under the `Develop` menu on Safari.