# Disable safari web-inspector

Tags: ios, uiwebview, safari-web-inspector

We are developing an iOS application as webapp. During development the possibility to remote debug the webapp in the UIWebView via safari web inspector is quite handy. But I'm wondering if there is any possibility to forbid this feature for the release version of our app even if the webinspector is activated in the iOS settings. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a related question:

[Why Safari shows "No Inspectable Applications" during remote debugging with iOS 6 device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999186/why-safari-shows-no-inspectable-applications-during-remote-debugging-with-ios)

Since we did not deploy for production yet but only for testing, our app was always inspectable.