# Using Web Inspector on Ipad: "No Inspectable Applications"

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

Trying to debug a website as displayed on the ipad by using the Safari web inspector. I can see the ipad in the Develop menu, but it only says "no inspectable applications" even when I have safari open. Have tried to restart both machines. Really stuck. The issue is a huge graphical bug that I see no other way to debug other than to understand the problem.

**Development Machine:**

Macbook Air

OS X 10.9.6

Safari on that OS: Version 7.0.6 (9537.78.2)

**Testing Device:**

Ipad

Version: 8.0.2

iOS: 8.0.2

Safari: unknown - when I run the "javascript:alert(...)" trick I get an error that says "Cannot Run Script"

Any clues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safari web inspector "No Inspectable Applications" when ipad connected to mac book pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225171/safari-web-inspector-no-inspectable-applications-when-ipad-connected-to-mac-bo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Safari shows "No Inspectable Applications" during remote debugging with iOS 6 device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999186/why-safari-shows-no-inspectable-applications-during-remote-debugging-with-ios)

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue, and tried many of the suggestions.

It was finally clearing out my Web Cache on iOS that allowed me to Web-Inspect.

Prior to that, and these things may have helped..

1. Closed and re-started iPad Safari
2. Closed and re-started iMac Safari
3. Restarted the iPad
4. Cleared WebCache iOS Safari (in Settings > Safari) 'Clear History and Website Data'

Item 4. was the one that made it work for me.

My next Step, before becoming completely frustrated and phoning Apple, would have been to re-start my iMac, but both of these, for me, turned out to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the EXACT same issue, I had some coworkers try and they got it running. I had just updated my safari to 7.0.6, but they had 7.1. I updated to safari version 7.1 on my mac and now it works... connect the ipad, load up the page, connect to safari on the mac and develop drop down. All works like it should. Hope it fixes your issue too.

***Note: mobile/ipad safari version are linked to the IOS version. Apparently you cannot get a different version of safari on your phone or ipad without updating the IOS.

Comment: Mine started working after the weekend with no update, no changes made... it was just there. I've no idea why.

Comment: That is weird, seems to be a common issue trying to get it to connect the first time. But from what I've heard it pretty much works after the first connection, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I am running OS X Mavericks 10.9.5 on an MacBook Air 11" and am trying to debug a webpage on Safari on different versions of iOS and on different devices (iPad, iPhone). Web Inspector is enabled on all of those devices and they are either connected through the lightning or the old connector cable and USB to the Mac. Every device appears in the Develop menu of Safari 7.0, however, the menu just says "No Inspectable Applications", although Safari is running on each machine, with a couple of tabs open. The same happens for another MacBook of a colleague. To top it off, some iDevices work, but just a minority of them, and so far, there is no pattern. And I am quite sure one iPhone 5 that used to work, now doesn't and, as far as I can see, none of the relevant parameters were changed on either of the machines, mobile or desktop.

Comment: This is more of a "note to self" kind of thing, but maybe it will help others facing the same problem: The iDevice application supposed to be shown in the Develop menu has to BE THE FRONTMOST application (sorry for shouting). If Safari is open on the iDevice, but not the frontmost application, it will not show up in the menu. I don't know if that goes without saying, but it cost me quite a while to find that out.

Answer (score 0):

To inspect an app with Safari's web inspector, the device needs to have a development provisioning profile for that app installed.