# Safari web inspector "No Inspectable Applications" when ipad connected to mac book pro

Tags: ios, macos, ipad, safari, safari-web-inspector

I have been searching/reading over the steps to set up the web inspector from an ipad on the mac. It all seems straight forward and it always shows the ipad connected in the develop drop down (in safari on the mac). But it never allows anything to be selected from my ipad (**“No Inspectable Applications”**), no matter what site I have pulled up in safari on my ipad.

I have a second gen Ipad 32 Gig
IOS version 8.0.2 (I started with 7.0.1 then upgraded to 7.0.2 then 8)

I am using a Mac Book Pro
IOS 10.9.5

Safari 
Version 7.0.6

Initially it was not syncing with my itunes when connected to the Mac, but I was still seeing the ipad connected (I just couldn't selected anything from the develop drop down **“No Inspectable Applications”**). I updated to the newer version on the ipad, and now I see my name attached to the ipad in the safari drop down on my mac. But it still does not allow me to actually select any applications regardless of what site I have loaded up in safari on my ipad.

I have tried restarted/updating both my mac and the ipad, I have started and stopped safari on the mac after connecting to the ipad... Still nothing. I am not really sure what I am doing wrong or if this is just a bug?

[This seems like the same issue posted 3 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26177148/using-web-inspector-on-ipad-no-inspectable-applications)

```
*** UPDATED TO: 
My version numbers that worked were: 
Mac Book Pro IOS: 10.9.5, 
Safari Version: 7.1, 
iPad IOS: 8.0.2, 
Xcode: 6.0.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Safari shows "No Inspectable Applications" during remote debugging with iOS 6 device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999186/why-safari-shows-no-inspectable-applications-during-remote-debugging-with-ios)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you need to install Xcode on the Mac, and also use Xcode (in the organizer) to set the iPad to be "use for Development."  Also make sure your Safari version is up to date, as well. Apparently, all versions need to be updated for success.

Comment: I actually did that right before I posted the question. I guess I didn't notice there was a message about the version:

The version of iOS on “Alan’s iPad” is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

OS Installed on Alan’s iPad
8.0.2 (12A405)

But I was using a lower version before, and I am pretty sure this is the latest version. Since I just updated. Thanks for your post.

Comment: If the iPad has 8.0.2, then you'll need Xcode 6.0.1.

Comment: Ya, so I downloaded Xcode 6.0.1 which ended up being a headache. But still not able to connect through safari. I can see it is using my device in xcode, and if I go to debug->view debugging->take screen shot of Alan's ipad takes a screen shot from my ipad. But still getting the "No Inspectable Applications" in Safari's develop, regardless of what is loaded up. I tried to go to launch a test app to the ipad it says "Xcode can request a new iOS Development signing identity for you." then "To request a signing identity, you need to add an Apple ID account that is enrolled in a Developer Program"

Comment: Ok after having some coworkers try and give me their stats, it ended up that my safari version was 7.0.6 after updating and theirs was at 7.1. If you add into your answer that ALL versions need to be up to date Mac and iPad IOS as well as safari(Mac) and Xcode I will accept it. My version numbers that worked were: Mac Book Pro IOS 10.9.5, Safari Version 7.1, iPad IOS 8.0.2, Xcode 6.0.1

Comment: It's a funny thing in that it's usually hard to set it up, but once you do, it seems to continue through subsequent updates OK.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting to read a lot of answers but no one that just said to you ***Update your Safari***.

Yeah, you don't need XCode to be installed, just **Safari 7.1**. And it's a simple update that you can do from the Mac App Store.

Comment: Actually Yosemite offers Safari 8, and Safari 7.1 can be installed in Mavericks too :)