# Safari: `no inspectable applications` for webpage

Tags: debugging, safari, mobile-safari, web-inspector

I'm trying to debug a webpage in mobile Safari and getting `no inspectable applications`.

I've seen this question pop up for Phone Gap and iOS/Xcode issues, but this is stricly for a webpage.

### Steps to reproduce:

*using Safari `10.1.2` and OS X `10.12.6`*

- I've enabled `Web Inspector` on mobile Safari.
- I've enabled `Develop` menu on desktop Safari.
- I open localhost:3000 in desktop Safari.

Under `Develop` menu, I see my phone, but the menu shows `no inspectable applications`.

All the information on the internet I can find just shows the steps I've detailed above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Safari shows "No Inspectable Applications" during remote debugging with iOS 6 device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999186/why-safari-shows-no-inspectable-applications-during-remote-debugging-with-ios)